# Django + Lighttpd

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am having some trouble getting django and lighttpd setup.

Here ist what I want to do:

1. Have lighttpd manage the fascgi processes (they both are run on the same server)
2. Have the django app run at the root of the site (so no django.fcgi)

Alternativly I could start django on startup, but I would need a start/stop script for ubuntu/debian.

Also how do I handle the media / admin media urls?  Also I would like to serve /css /js /img from the document root ...

TIA
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

https://github.com/cdsi/elrond/blob/master/etc/lighttpd.conf

https://github.com/cdsi/elrond/blob/master/var/www/elrond.wsgi

Be sure to update the env.ELROND_XXX paths accordingly, and change:

```
fastcgi.server          = ("/elrond" =>
```

to:

```
fastcgi.server          = ("/" =>
```